# Using variable within define quotes

Tags: c

Say I want to create a function which receives a DR (Debug register) id number and returns the value of the corresponding DR register.

Something like (Example for DR0) :

```
uint64_t readdr(uint8_t id)
{
   uint64_t result;
   asm volatile("movq %%dr0, %%rax\n" : "=a" (result));
   return result;
}
```

This example just reads the DR0 register and returns the result.
I want this function to work for all the DR's so I need something like :

```
#define read_dr(x, result) "movq %%dr(x), %%rax\n" : "=a" (result)"
```

and then i'll be able to do something like this:

```
asm volatile(read_dr(id, result))
```

so it will work for all given DR ids.

I know it's not working but I just hope that it will clarify what i'm trying to achieve.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check out the stringify and concatenation operators. cf. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html (not sure it is possible but if it is then with those).

Comment: The define wouldn't help because `id` is a variable, not an integer literal. So you can't embed it into an assembly instruction.

Comment: Can you write such a function in assembly?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on whether id is known at compile time.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define read_dr(id, result) \
   __asm__ ( \
      "movq %%dr%c1, %0" \
      : "=r" (result) \
      : "i" (id) \
      : "cc")

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   long long a;
   read_dr(1, a);
   printf("%lld\n", a);
}
```

If at any time the compiler cannot resolve id to a constant, you'll get compile errors (impossible constraint).

Note that reading debug registers is a privileged instruction.  Also, this is 64bit code (a slightly fancier version would work for both 32 and 64bit).  Finally, while this can work as a macro, I doubt this will work as an actual function (except maybe a forceinline one).